# Return type is not assignable to unknown using TypeScript 5 decorators

Tags: typescript, decorator

Trying to implement the new TypeScript 5 decorators, but I'm facing a typing issue that I do not understand.
Below is the simple example, [TS PLAYGROUND HERE](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.3#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwDYQDmhwAJgLLAwAWEpAPACrWYDOANHAIJSGtygYwFKX4BDFAE8A2gF1OAJSpIoKTgDFcg4aLgAKGmwBccZm04A6K2N6sTPPgEo4AXgB8cJTBUo3egFBwcDA2JDAmmuyBcGg4QiDhcADCeGKsrJQ0dAAiwLFQYjDQSXGCTCwccJpu-s4A3tGxKKzwALZUtKQAcmLtrnAAyjBQmCiEek3xMBYovcCOANzRyOhYOHBQwGCpaMDtKDCZnQYVJmaVVhahdty2jiZePnANQUFNrBB4wBYE4wAGABkAPIAcTgJgAogdgCMxnAjnQ4AAiAAkdXaWW6cwAvki-otom8cC0NsBWEg8PAXMFQlQLGgxHg8CdzHBLtcCa8YsTPt9fnpAaDwXAISBMFg4QjSMi0RjOj12rj8UsuZtvKpSeTKSq4Nj-NE1U9NtsxLt9ocOnQlnr-DBJGBgKYAApQOhIDCsbJFIFIGBgX39F6vRl4IwtWGEfw2-ygSCwGKpdJwF1uj0DGEAN0wu2e0QAAr8SBRLaRomlJOg4GEuEy9K0IGgANYp0jumB2CSSe7J12tNjAJgttue72%20-0wOQeINE5rwTZaqlwetNoceiytMRgPR6MCu1sYIyd5zuXNcoIAenPAlYeFGMAAtKQ2GIAEZfe8oQT32%20fuB5u0OqwaAjGAD5kj%20MDnigED3qgSCsGQ94ZjYrCEq87zwHUcCYKQlhWPO8DYv0u6pjASxoUEhoagRcBpM6e7Dl6EA%20n6vo6kE2Kcq8VG4POFIwNEerYkAA)

Error is:

> ```
>    Decorator function return type '(this: ProductsService, ...args: any[]) => unknown' is not assignable to type 'void | ((mockProducts: any) => Promise<TProductsDtoOutput[]>)'.
>      Type '(this: ProductsService, ...args: any[]) => unknown' is not assignable to type '(mockProducts: any) => Promise<TProductsDtoOutput[]>'.
>        Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'Promise<TProductsDtoOutput[]>'.
> ```

```
export function loggedMethod<This, Args extends any[], Return, Fn extends (this: This, ...args: Args) => Return>(
  target: Fn,
  context: ClassMethodDecoratorContext<This, Fn>
) {
  const methodName = String(context.name);
  function replacementMethod(this: This, ...args: Args): Return {
    console.log(`LOG : Entering Method "${methodName}"`);
    const result = target.call(this, ...args);
    console.log(`LOG : Exiting Method "${methodName}"`);
    return result;
  }

  return replacementMethod;
}

type TProductsDtoOutput = {
    all:string
}


export class ProductsService {
  @loggedMethod
  async getAll(mockProducts:any): Promise<TProductsDtoOutput[]> {
    const result = mockProducts.map((product:any) => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
      const { id, ...rest } = product;

      return rest as TProductsDtoOutput;
    });
    return result
  }
}
```

[EDIT]
Add picture
[image: Error remain the same even when casting return type]

Comment: There's no inference site for `This` or `Return` in your code; constraints aren't used as inference sites.  I'm not sure why you need the `Fn` generic type (can you explain that?) but if you *do* need it then you'll need to compute `This` and `Return` from it explicitly, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mqYYkm). Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yep, what you are suggesting is correct, and I had also casting the return type. What is weird is that, I have copy/paste you code in my program, and I still got the error. The  ProductService class is a nestJS injectable. Might be the issue, but can not import NestJs in the TS Playground. Will add a screenshot to show that error remain the sale

Comment: I don't know what to do with a screenshot (aside than to point out that [it should be plaintext instead](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)).  If you can't provide a [mre] then I can't really help.  I can either answer the question as asked, which fixes the problem as stated, or wait until such time as you provide a standalone [mre] that demonstrates the continued problem you're having.  How would you like to proceed?

Comment: as I mentionned, the example is in the TS playground : this is exactly the same code as in this post, except the nestJS decorator `@Injectable()` that I could not add in TS Playground. When copying  your TS Playground code in lymy TS file, error remains whereas it is no longer in the playground. Will further investigate why

Comment: I'm a little concerned that you're apparently trying to use old-style deprecated decorators together with the new JS decorators; I doubt you'll be successful doing that.  Regardless, either your question depends on nestJS, in which case it should be tagged as such, or it does not, in which case your problem with nestJS's decorator is out of scope for the question and you should deal with it offline.  Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

TS does not infer first generics in this case. Infer them manually then this will work.

```
export function loggedMethod<Fn extends (...args: any[]) => any>(
  target: Fn,
  context: ClassMethodDecoratorContext<ThisParameterType<Fn>, Fn>
) {
  const methodName = String(context.name);
  return function replacementMethod(this: ThisParameterType<Fn>, ...args: Parameters<Fn>) {
    console.log(`LOG : Entering Method "${methodName}"`);
    const result = target.call(this, ...args);
    console.log(`LOG : Exiting Method "${methodName}"`);
    return result;
  }
}
```